# Is Redis DB suitable for desktop application?

Tags: redis

I am working on simple desktop application in LUA. This application is extracting software artifacts and storing them to key-value database in graphs structures. I am exploring which db will be better to use, considering tokyo cabinet and redis. But redis is server based db, so my question is if it is suitable for application like that. Or point me of some better solution. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Is't Redis more suitable for high performance applications and not for standalone desktop applications?

Yes , it is , but it can also serve well for stand alone desktop application.I have used redis for in pretty much both scenario's and I am happy in both the cases.

Here, I can recommend you to look for ease of integration and for the one which gives you more functionalities and meet your expectations more closely.

Comment: Thank you @Jain Rack ! How do you deploy such a desktop application? Redis consists of a server and one/more clients. Having the app act as the client is easy, but how about the server? Do you start it from your app? Thanks

Comment: Definitely redis server will be a prerequisite for such a application .Redis server will run as windows service , more like other services .

Comment: Definitely redis server will be a prerequisite for such a application . Redis server runs as windows service , more like other windows services . During app installation , you can make sure that everytime system boots up redis service should also come up (just like any other startup service) . Don't worry it won't take lot of resources

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you want your desktop app to store to key-value database. I will vote for redis since most developers used them instead of tokyo but I could be wrong.

In terms of practice, If you want key-value store database use Redis since the database itself is focused on key-value storage and it already have networking capabilities and scalability.

The downside will probably be in hardware specs for redis. You will have to code thinking of the minimum memory requirement and limiting the stuffs you are storing into the RAM as much as possible. However, nowadays memories are getting bigger, better and cheaper.

In Tokyo Cabinet it can process larger stuffs than the memory itself. Which is why I think that you have considered it due to that fact.

Even if Tokyo has better memory management, I will still go for Redis.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is't Redis more suitable for high performance applications and not for standalone desktop applications?

Comment: They have pointed out a better version of of Tokyo Cabinet http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/.

Well I believe that any software are high performance. It is only limited by hardware.

Comment: Remember that there is no official port on Windows for Redis. There is an unofficial one but has some disadvatanges that the original doesn't have such as: "stop the world dumping redis".